# How do I remove this wheel bolts cover

Tags: wheels

I bought this car with aftermarket wheels and I am trying to remove the wheel bolts cover to get to the bolts but the question is how do I remove the cover?

[image: Rims stud cover]

Sorry for the unclear photo but it seems to be held on by some odd shaped bolts, do those require a special key that comes with rims to uncover? what if the previous owner doesn't have the key, is there a way to remove them?

Comment: some of those hub covers aren't really bolted on maybe grab a plastic pry bar and lightly pry on it see if it'll pop off. the "bolts" in question look like hex bolts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the wheel for any manufacturers marks and if you find them, contact the manufacturer for advice.  There are a number of methods or removal, some are push-pull fit, some a threaded, etc...

However, the universal answer will be to properly identify the wheel make and model and check with the manufacturer.  If you can't identify any markings on the wheel, check aftermarket performance catalogs and magazines to see if you can spot a match that way.